# Retrieving text value from ENUM by using int number that doesn't exist in said ENUM returns that int number in C#?

Tags: c#, enums

I was reading official Microsoft C# documentation and examples on ENUM and there is a code in example that I don't understand.

```
public enum Season
{
    Spring,
    Summer,
    Autumn,
    Winter
}

public class EnumConversionExample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Season a = Season.Autumn;
        Console.WriteLine($"Integral value of {a} is {(int)a}");  // output: Integral value of Autumn is 2

        var b = (Season)1;
        Console.WriteLine(b);  // output: Summer

        var c = (Season)4;
        Console.WriteLine(c);  // output: 4
    }
}
```

The code block in question is

```
var c = (Season)4;
```

Documentation says that values in ENUM are associated with INTs that start with 0 and increase by 1 for each next value. So by this logic, Spring is 0, Summer is 1, Autumn is 2 and Winter is 3. There is no ENUM value associated with 4, yet VS shows not error and prints 4 when I run it.

I don't understand this behavior and it looks strange that VS doesn't mark this code block as error or warning. Wouldn't it be better to let a program crash to prevent more bugs when you try to retrieve a value from ENUM that doesn't even exist?

Comment: An enum can represent the complete range of values of the backing type typically an int. Just some will have names (or multiple names). Your expectations about enums might not fit the reality. For checking a value exists as "named" value see [IsDefined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=net-8.0#system-enum-isdefined(system-type-system-object)).

Comment: An enum is essentially just the code pretending it's not an int and giving you some fancy code completion and readability. So yes, you can assign any number you like to an enum value. If you want to put your own check in place, you can use `Enum.IsDefined<Season>((Season)4)` which would give you `false` in your case.

Comment: This statement is completely wrong: `Documentation says that values in ENUM are associated with INTs that start with 0 and increase by 1 for each next value. `

Comment: You're confused because you don't see that `public enum Season` really is `public enum Season : int`. But can be `public enum Season : byte/short/long`. And if you don't have a matching enum member, it simply returns value assigned.  Here `var c = (Season)4;` is actually `Season c = (Season)4;` and in IL definition will look like a class with `.field public static literal valuetype Season Winter = int32(3)`

Comment: The doc you are looking at (for `enum`, not ENUM) includes that example code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum#conversions. It explains that conversions from the underlying integral type to the `enum` type are possible for any value of the underlying integral type (if it is outside of the enum's range, the result of a `ToString` conversion is equivalent to `int.ToString`). You may disagree with the design, but it is what it is.